# when creating a data, it hasn't name

Tags: r, dataframe

```
dataset=structure(list(goods = structure(1:6, .Label = c("a", "b", "c", 
"d", "e", "f"), class = "factor")), .Names = "goods", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

  goods
1     a
2     b
3     c
4     d
5     e
6     f
```

i want create new data, simple  i do

```
df1=dataset$goods
```

but after it df1  doesn't have name column goods.
Why?

```
str(df1)
 Factor w/ 6 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

As you can see it hasn't name `goods`
How to do that df1 data has name column goods?

If this post is dublicate, let me know, i delete it.

Comment: df1 is a vector, not a data frame, `df1=data.frame(goods=dataset$goods)`.

Comment: @user2974951, it works.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning a column vector, not a data frame. To assign the whole data frame, simply do

```
df = dataset
```

If you want to preserve only some columns and not all, use [column subsetting](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html) ([documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html)):

```
df = dataset[, "goods", drop = FALSE]
```

`drop = FALSE` is necessary here because the dataframe subset operator will otherwise return a vector instead of a data frame with a single column (this is arguably a bug, which is why tidyverse tibbles behave differently).

Using tidyverse operations (aka the “modern” R way), this would be written as

```
library(dplyr)
```

```
df = select(dataset, goods)
```

Answer (score 0):

`df1=data.frame(goods=dataset$goods, stringsAsFactors=F)` works perfectly well, or you can use the longer but (somewhat?) more explicit:

```
ds <- dataset[,c("goods")]
df1=data.frame(goods=dataset$goods)
library(dplyr)
ds <- dataset[,c("goods")] %>% as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors=F)
colnames(ds) <- "goods"
```

edit: Added the stringsAsFactors option as it is useful to control where you'd like factor conversion or not. `c("goods")`  is equivalent to `"goods"`, but I left it as a template in case you need to add more columns.

Comment: Don’t write `c("goods")`, it’s identical to `"goods"`. Furthermore, R does **not** consider a 1-column DF as a vector. Lastly, don’t use `require`, use `library` exclusively.